# PHPOffice - PowerPoint : How do I draw a dashed line in my PowerPoint slide?

Tags: php, powerpoint, phpoffice

I want to generate a dashed line in my PowerPoint presentation using PHPOffice but I can only generate solid or double lines.

Line Generator Code

```
$shape->getBorder()
      ->setColor($color)
      ->setLineStyle(Border::LINE_SOLID);
```

How do I properly generate a dashed line?

Dash Generation Code

```
$shape->getBorder()->setDashStyle(Border::DASH_DASH);
```

Comment: Looks like you got this working, but as to your original problem, did you check for warnings in your log file? Specifically about undefined constants due to namespace issues?

Comment: Hi @miken32, I tried to disable rendering of PowerPoint by commenting out my header() lines in PHP  I will try to enable warnings. I saw nothing but a blank screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following scheme to generate a dashed line.

I resorted to generating short line segments of constant length regardless of orientation of start end point (slope of line).

How I generated the short line segments for sloped line of equal length was in several steps.

**Algorithm**

```
 0)  Initialize dashLen to an arbitrary value so that we increment to
     2x dashlen on each iteration of loop to cause empty holes to appear in
     line 
 1)  Calculate length of line    d=sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy) 
 2)  Calculate negative slope since in the y axis is flipped (Y increases as points traverse screen space in downward direction)
 3)  Loop $x and $y and
     increment $y such that 
     $y += 2*$dashLen*sin(atan($m));
     $x -= 2*$dashLen*cos(atan($m));
 4)  Update endpoints

     $endY = $startY + (($dashLen)*sin(atan($m))); 
     $endX = $startX - (($dashLen)*cos(atan($m))); 
 5)  Draw Line Segments (dashes)
```

**Code Snippet**

```
$d = sqrt(pow($toY-$fromY, 2) + pow($toX-$fromX, 2));
if ($toX != $fromX)
{
      $m = ($toY-$fromY)/($fromX-$toX);
      $dashLen = 2;
      for ($y = $fromY, $x = $fromX; $y < $toY || $x > $toX; $y += ((2*$dashLen*sin(atan($m)))), $x -= (2*$dashLen*cos(atan($m))))
      {   
          $startX = $x;
          $startY = $y;

          $endY = $startY + (($dashLen)*sin(atan($m))); 
          $endX = $startX - (($dashLen)*cos(atan($m)));

          $shape = $currentSlide->createLineShape($startX, $startY, $endX, $endY);


          $color = new Color('FF000000');


          $shape->getFill()
                ->setFillType(Fill::FILL_SOLID)
                ->setStartColor($color)
                ->setEndColor($color);
          $shape->getBorder()
                ->setColor($color)->setLineWidth(2)
                ->setLineStyle($this->getCategoryLine($category));  
      } 
}
else
{

      $dashLen = 2;
      for ($y = $toY; $y > $fromY; $y -= 2*$dashLen)
      {   
          $startX = $fromX;
          $startY = $y;
          $endX = $toX;
          $endY = $y - ($dashLen);             

          $shape = $currentSlide->createLineShape($startX, $startY, $endX, $endY);

          $color = new Color('FF000000');
           $shape->getFill()
                 ->setFillType(Fill::FILL_SOLID)
                 ->setStartColor($color)
                 ->setEndColor($color);
           $shape->getBorder()
                 ->setColor($color)->setLineWidth(2)
                 ->setLineStyle(); 
      }  
}
```

[image]